# How can I get my unnumbered chapter to appear in the table of contents?

Tags: table-of-contents

I use an unnumbered chapter for my abstract, followed by the table of contents. However, that unnumbered chapter does not appear in the ToC. How can I fix this?

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper, oneside, bold]{thesis}
\usepackage[left=3cm,right=2cm,top=3cm,bottom=2cm]{geometry}
\begin{document}
\chapter*{abstract}
\tableofcontents
\chapter{1}
\chapter{2}
\chapter{3}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look on [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: In short:
\chapter*{Results} %do not add the nomber
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Results} % add to the table of contents